# How to add Page Action Custom Button on Magento 2 admin pages

Tags: magento2, admin, toolbar

I am developing one module in which I need to add a custom buttons on Magento 2 admin pages(Like: category Page, Product Grid Page, Orders Grid Page).

I need to add button on the below bar, which is available on every magento admin page.

[image]

Please let me know, if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy with Magento 2, if your already have your module declared.

Let's imagine i want to add a "Clear Category Cache" button on Category Admin :

[image: Adding Magento 2 admin button]

Admin buttons are declared in "UI Components" file, usually located in `vendor/magento/MAGENTO_MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component\FILE.xml`.

For Categories, the file is located in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`.

Let's create a copy in your module, to override the core one, in `YOUR_NAMESPACE/YOUR_MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="clear_cache" class="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\ClearCacheButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</form>
```

Finally, create your button file

```php
<?php

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AbstractCategory;

/**
 * Class ClearCacheButton
 */
class ClearCacheButton extends AbstractCategory implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Clear Cache button
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        $categoryId = (int)$category->getId();

        if ($categoryId) {
            return [
                'id' => 'clear_cache',
                'label' => __('Clear Category Cache'),
                'on_click' => "alert('ok')",
                'class' => 'delete',
                'sort_order' => 10
            ];
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same way store switcher is implemented by adding a custom block template in page layout xml inside body -> main.page.actions

This is how store switcher is added:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
        <action method="setUseConfirm">
            <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="your_ui_components"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```