# Magento 2: How to get current category id in admin controller

Tags: magento2, category, admin-controller

I have made a custom button on category edit page in admin. The button redirects to custom admin controller. I need to fetch the current category id in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can get this by following code

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Comment: Category id is not included in the params

Comment: you need to pass it as parameter on your button

Comment: Thanks. I passed the id as a parameter to the controller.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 3):

You can get by using Magento\Framework\Registry in the constructor of your block file.

```
class Testblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry) 
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->('current_category');
    }
}
```

Then you can get current category ID as below:

```
$this->getCurrentCategory->getId();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the category id to the button .

Let assume that you have added the button using block class files like the https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260643/4564

`$categoryId = (int)$category->getId();`

add

```
onclick="window.location.href='<?php $this->getUrl('frontentId/Controllername/ActioName',['category_id'=> $categoryId])?>';"
```